# Section head style with memoir class and tex4ebook

Tags: sectioning, memoir, tex4ebook

Tex4ebook seems to ignore the \setsecheadstyle command with the memoir class.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[ebook,12pt,oneside,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setsecheadstyle{\normalsize\itshape\raggedright}

\title{Book}
\author{Author}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents \newpage

\mainmatter

\chapter{C1}

\section{S1}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Running normal Latex gives an italic section heading:

[image: Latex output]

Running tex4ebook gives the default bold section heading:

[image: Tex4ebook output]

Is there any way to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the section format using custom CSS rule. First of all, you need to find the element which needs to configure in the HTML file:

```html
<h3 class="sectionHead"><span class="titlemark">1.1   </span> <a 
 id="x1-30001.1"></a>S1</h3>
```

In this case, we need to configure `h3` element with `sectionHead` class. We can then use the following CSS in the `.cfg` file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{h3.sectionHead{font-style:italic;font-weight:normal;}}
\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I am still confused about when you have to add custom css code to the config file. Are there any guidelines for this or is it trial and error? Thanks again.

Comment: @user41974 tex4ht tries to preserve the document structure mainly. The styling is done by some default CSS styles, so if you want to change appearance of something, you usually need to figure out how it is encoded in the HTML file and provide your custom CSS.