# Memory error with tabular and latest Tex4ebook running on Texlive 2018

Tags: tables, memoir, tex4ebook, texlive-2018

This is a followup of my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470352/faulty-chapter-header-with-latest-tex4ebook-running-on-texlive-2018) and uses the same MWE and the config file provided by michal.h21.

MWE

```
\documentclass[ebook,12pt,oneside,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setsecheadstyle{\normalsize\itshape\raggedright}%

\title{Book}
\author{Author}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents \newpage

\mainmatter

\chapter{C1}

\section{S1}

\begin{tabular}{p{0.3\hsize}p{0.7\hsize}}%
a & b\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Css{h3.sectionHead{font-style:italic;font-weight:normal;}}
\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

This gives an error message running Tex4book:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\n:@startpbox: ...\expandafter \o:@startpbox: \fi
                                                  {#1}\expandafter \everypar...
l.26     a
           & b\\
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

It worked previously without any problems.

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that some packages have been recently removed from Memoir:

> Changed (2018/12/12)
>
> o memoir v3.7h
>
> -- The following packages are no longer embedded into the class    sources: array, delarray, dcolumn and tabularx.

`tex4ht` config file for Memoir includes configurations for these packages and it seems there is a clash somewhere. Fortunately, disabling loading of these files from `memoir.4ht` seems to fix the error:

```
% memoir.4ht (2019-01-16-14:31), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2003-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2019 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2019-01-16-14:31}

\input book.4ht
\input verse.4ht
% Table handling:
% \input array.4ht
% \input dcolumn.4ht
% \input tabularx.4ht
\input booktabs.4ht
\let\columnlines\empty

\let\rm\empty
\let\sf\empty
\let\tt\empty
\let\bf\empty
\let\it\empty

\def\@chapter[#1]#2{%
   \gHAdvance\:mpNum by 1
\HAssign\minipageNum=\:mpNum \relax
%
   {\SkipRefstepAnchor \let\addcontentsline\:gobbleIII\no@chapter[#1]{}%
    \global\let\f@rtoc\f@rtoc
    \ifx\f@rtoc\empty\gdef\f@rtoc{#2}\fi
    \global\let\f@rhdr\f@rhdr  }%
   \HtmlEnv   \Toc:Title{\f@rtoc}\:chapter{#2}}
\def\:tempc{\@ifstar\o:tableofcontents:\o:tableofcontents:}
\HLet\tableofcontents\:tempc
\NewConfigure{poemline}{2}
\NewConfigure{legend}{2}
\renewcommand\legend[1]{\a:legend #1\b:legend}

\ifx \memgobble\:UnDef
   \pend:defI\getthelinenumber{%
   \let\sv:thepoemline\thepoemline
   \pend:def\thepoemline{\a:poemline}%
   \append:def\thepoemline{\b:poemline}}
\append:defI\getthelinenumber{\let\thepoemline\sv:thepoemline}

\else
   \pend:defII\getthelinenumber{%
   \let\sv:thepoemline\thepoemline
   \pend:def\thepoemline{\a:poemline}%
   \append:def\thepoemline{\b:poemline}}
\append:defII\getthelinenumber{\let\thepoemline\sv:thepoemline}

   \let\no@Msect\M@sect
\NewConfigure{@sec @ssect}[1]{%
   \def\rdef:sec##1{#1\csname no@##1\endcsname}}
\:CheckOption{sections-}     \if:Option
   \Configure{@sec @ssect}{}
\else
   \Configure{@sec @ssect}{%
      \let\sv:Sc\:Sc \let\sv:sect\@sect \let\sv:ssect\@ssect
\let\sv:Msect\M@sect
\let\:Sc\:gobble
      \def\M@sect##1##2##3##4##5##6[##7][##8]##9{%
   \ifx \o:@seccntformat:\:UnDef
  \let\o:@seccntformat:\@seccntformat
\fi
\let\@seccntformat\:gobble
%
   \let\M@sect\no@Msect   \xdef\c:secnumdepth{##2}%
   {\SkipRefstepAnchor \let\addcontentsline\:gobbleIII \let\mark\:gobble
    \no@Msect{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}{##5}{##6}[{##7}][{##8}]{}}%
   \let\:Sc\sv:Sc \let\@sect\sv:sect \let\@ssect\sv:ssect
\let\M@sect\sv:Msect
%
   \let\@seccntformat=\o:@seccntformat:
%
   \HtmlEnv    \Toc:Title{##8}\csname no:#1\endcsname{##9}}%
%
      \def\@sect##1##2##3##4##5##6[##7]##8{%
   \ifx \o:@seccntformat:\:UnDef
  \let\o:@seccntformat:\@seccntformat
\fi
\let\@seccntformat\:gobble
%
   \let\@sect\no@sect   \xdef\c:secnumdepth{##2}%
   {\SkipRefstepAnchor \let\addcontentsline\:gobbleIII \let\mark\:gobble
    \no@sect{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}{##5}{##6}[{##7}]{}}%
   \let\:Sc\sv:Sc \let\@sect\sv:sect \let\@ssect\sv:ssect
\let\M@sect\sv:Msect
%
   \let\@seccntformat=\o:@seccntformat:
%
   \HtmlEnv    \Toc:Title{##7}\csname no:#1\endcsname{##8}}%
%
      \def\@ssect##1##2##3##4##5{%
   \gdef\ssect:ttl{##5}%
%
   \let\@ssect\no@ssect
   {\def\addcontentsline####1####2####3{}%
    \no@ssect{##1}{##2}{##3}{##4}{}}%
   \let\:Sc\sv:Sc \let\@sect\sv:sect \let\@ssect\sv:ssect
\let\M@sect\sv:Msect
%
   \HtmlEnv   \csname :like#1\endcsname{##5}}%
\IgnorePar}
\fi

\fi
\Hinput{memoir}
\endinput
```

[image]